# On page break footer gets disappeared in google doc

Tags: google-docs

Thanks for the help in advance. I am creating a google doc. In it I have added header and footer.On page break the footer disappears from the first and but it appears in the second. I want the footer  to appear in all pages irrespective of page break. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Before page break
[image]

After page break
[image]

Comment: Please share a copy of your google doc